# How to close a window and specify expansion of the remaining windows?

Tags: vim

Is it possible in vim to close a window and specify which one will fill the remaining space?

Say having a "six-pak" layout and closing the top left window X I would like to set that bottom window (B) would expand and fill the space occupied by the closed window and not the one to the right (A):

```
----------------------- //Closing top left window X
|       |       |     |
|    X  |   A   |     |
|       |       |     |
-----------------------
|       |       |     |
|   B   |       |     |
|       |       |     |
-----------------------

----------------------- //The desired result B is expanded upwards
|       |       |     |
|       |   A   |     |
|       |       |     |
|   B   |--------------
|       |       |     |
|       |       |     |
|       |       |     |
-----------------------

----------------------- //Actual result
|          |          |
|     A    |          |
|          |          |
-----------------------
|       |       |     |
|   B   |       |     |
|       |       |     |
-----------------------
```

---

### EDIT

I am looking for a generic solution not necessarily closing the top left window. I would like to specify any adjacent window to fill the current window position. This could be closing the middle bottom one and specifying the right bottom one to expand.

Comment: You essentially want an IDE-like [layout manager for vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/layoutManager), or perhaps a [Vim plugin for an existing IDE such as Eclipse](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) would help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these three steps:

1. Close the top left window.

   :q
2. Move to the lower left window.

   CTRL-W w CTRL-W w
3. Move the lower left window to the far left.

   CTRL-w H

You could then record these commands to a register to save keystrokes, e.g.,

```
let @q = ":q^M^Ww^Ww^Ww^WH"
```

Comment: It solves the example problem, but I am looking for a generic solution (see clarification of the question). Do you think that such solution exists? or should I do something similar for a specific case (Ctrl-w HLKJ) ?

Answer (score 1):

if your cursor in window `X`:

```
Ctrl-W j Ctrl-W H Ctrl-W p :q
```

if your cursor may be in any window, try:

```
Ctrl-W t Ctrl-W j Ctrl-W H Ctrl-W p :q
```

Comment: Please check the clarification of my question. Do you know if there is a simple generic solution?

Comment: @Kimi if you use multi-windows heavily, I suggest you trying a plugin dwm.vim

Answer (score 1):

You can put the following line in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <F2> :q \| wincmd j \| wincmd H <CR>
```

Explanation:

- `map <F2>` - functionality available by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>
- `q` - close the current window
- `wincmd j` - go to the bottom window
- `wincmd H` - move this (current) window to be at the far left

The `\|` is used to combine all this commands.

**Sources**

- [:help :\bar](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3a%5Cbar)
- [:help :wincmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3awincmd)